# IdentityServer3 How to redirect user from MVC Client application with signin=

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I'm new to OAuth 2.0 and IdentityServer3 but have a pretty good grasp on the inner workings and have an up and running implementation and client(s) using various Flows (implicit and etc...)

This maybe a noobie question but I've managed to configure a working IdentityServer3 implementation and working MVC Client using (Implicit Flow).

To force the user to the IdentityServer3 login page (which I've customized in a template), the client has to click the Login link within the Client and  ActionResult within the Client has an [Authorize] attribute, which redirects the user to the IdentityServer login page (because it requires Authorization).

Is this the correct implementation?  Also, I'd like to redirect the user to a separate Register page, but without adding an [Authorize] attribute to the Register action (which will redirect to the login page FIRST and it then the user has to click the "Register Link" which I customized through the use of templates) in the Client I can't seem to accomplish this.

How can I separate the Login logic from the Registration logic?

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks,

Comment: So I've figured out how to redirect a user to the server's (identityserver3) login page.  See below.   I'm using httpcontext.getowincontext().authentication.challenge(properties); method to redirect to login. However how do I redirect them to the Register page of the IdentityServer?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the `[Authorize]`-Attribute over your Register Page.
Because as you said correctly it would redirect to the login first.
It needs to be publicly available. To integrate a "**Register**"-Link in the Login-View you can use the following property in the `IdentityServerOptions`:

**Startup.cs** [Excerpt from IdentityServer-Configuration]

```
IdentityServerOptions options = new IdentityServerOptions
{
    AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions {
        LoginPageLinks = new List<LoginPageLink> {
            new LoginPageLink { Href = "https://example.com/register", Text = "Register" },
            new LoginPageLink { Href = "https://example.com/forgot-password", Text = "Forgot your password?"}
        }
    }
};
```

This will add the Links below the Login Form on the login-page of the identityserver.

Again mind that these links need to be **public** (without authorization)